# Get firebase data when selecting RecyclerView android

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I has two RecyclerView. For example, if I click recyclerview1, I want to take his rooms, and if I click recyclerview2, I want to take his rooms. I want to capture data based on my selected RecyclerView how can I do this? For example,

> if recyclerView1 is selected, "DatabaseReference refRooms =
>   mDatabase.child (chipNumberNew).child("Rooms");"
>
> if recyclerView2 is selected, I want to get "DatabaseReference =
>   mDatabase.child (chipNumberNewrecyclerView2).child ("Rooms");"

```
DatabaseReference refRooms = mDatabase.child(chipNumberNew).child("Rooms");
          refRooms.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
           public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        spinner = (Spinner)itemView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerMain);

   ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Rooms);
                            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
             spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
             String data = snapshot.getValue(String.class);  
               Rooms.add(data);
                            addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
     public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recyclerview on click listener and depending on what recyclerview was clicked you can call a method.